# ScrollReveal issue(?)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using ScrollReveal to animate some divs of my html file.
It works fine but I've noticed something:

- Using Google inspect to check on a mobile view, works fine;
- Viewing the page my desktop monitor (2560x1440, works fine;

But when I move the window to my laptop the .reveal-7 div just disappears. It starts doing the inverse animation. It seams its regarded with the size of the window because opening it on my desktop monitor and the resizing the window does that issue.

Any ideas why?

Here's my CSS code.

```
.reveal-1, .reveal-2, .reveal-3, .reveal-4, .reveal-5, .reveal-6, .reveal-7 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

My JS:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
window.sr = ScrollReveal({reset: 'true'});
sr.reveal('.reveal-1', {duration: 600});
sr.reveal('.reveal-2', {duration: 1200});
sr.reveal('.reveal-3', {duration: 1800});
sr.reveal('.reveal-4', {duration: 2400});
sr.reveal('.reveal-5', {duration: 3000});
sr.reveal('.reveal-6', {duration: 3600});
sr.reveal('.reveal-7', {duration: 4200});
```

})

My HTML example:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1 class="first-child reveal-1">Example</h1>
  
  <div class="card_festival ticket dashed-line reveal-2" style="background-image: url(assets/images/brunch.jpg)">
  <!--content here -->>
  </div>

  <!--Venda Final-->
  <div class="info_row reveal-3">
    <!--content here -->>
  </div>

  <!--Saldo Cashless-->
  <div class="info_row reveal-4">
    <!--content here -->>
  </div>

  <h1 class="reveal-5">Example</h1>

  <!--Card Festival-->
  <div class="card_festival reveal-6" style="background-image: url(assets/images/brunch.jpg)">
    <!--content here -->>
  </div>

  <!--Card Festival-->
  <div class="card_festival last-child reveal-7" style="background-image: url(assets/images/somnii_23.jpg)">
    <!--content here -->>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried changing the {reset:''} to once, or always on my window.sr = ScrollReveal({reset: 'true'}); to see if did anything or adding a ,mobile: 1300 to it but it didn't do anything (this is what I found on the web)

Comment: How could we possibly tell, based on nothing but such an overly vague description? Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @CBroe sorry, I'm not used to do this.. I'm still learning all this.
I've edited my post. Is it better now?